# Mat Autocomplete shows [object object] in the dropdown before the selection

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, autocomplete, mat-autocomplete

Used `{{option.name}}` but throws error

> TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'string'.

I have also tried changing the value, currently I have {option} in the list so the object is displayed, all other things like filter, selection, and on click is working but the display, please help

```
<form>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input type="text"  matInput  [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="myControl">
      <!-- <input type="text"  matInput  [matAutocomplete]="auto" /> -->
      <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]= "option" >
           {{option}}
          <!-- {{option.name}} --> // **strong text**
        </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

```
<form>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input type="text"  matInput  [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="myControl">
      <!-- <input type="text"  matInput  [matAutocomplete]="auto" /> -->
      <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]= "option" >
            <h1> {{option}}</h1>
          <!-- {{option.name}} --> // **strong text**
        </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ServicesService } from 'src/app/services.service';
import { FormBuilder, Validators, FormControl  } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-customer',
  templateUrl: './customer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./customer.component.scss']
})
export class CustomerComponent implements OnInit {

  op : any = []

  objectOptions :any
  checkforcustomer: any;
  options: any[] = [];
  isSubmitted=false;
  customerName: any;
  customerResponse:any;
  constructor(public fb: FormBuilder,public service:ServicesService) { }
  customerdetailForm = this.fb.group({
    customername: ['', [Validators.required]],
  });

  filteredOptions: Observable<string[]> | undefined

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // this.service.fetchDefaultCustomerdetails().subscribe((res) => {
    //   this.customerResponse=res[0]
    //   console.log('Customer Details here',this.customerResponse)
    // })
    // this.onSubmit();\
    this.options =[
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Leanne Graham",
        "username": "Bret",
        "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
        "address": {
          "street": "Kulas Light",
          "suite": "Apt. 556",
          "city": "Gwenborough",
          "zipcode": "92998-3874",
          "geo": {
            "lat": "-37.3159",
            "lng": "81.1496"
          }
        },
        "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
        "website": "hildegard.org",
        "company": {
          "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
          "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
          "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Ervin Howell",
        "username": "Antonette",
        "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
        "address": {
          "street": "Victor Plains",
          "suite": "Suite 879",
          "city": "Wisokyburgh",
          "zipcode": "90566-7771",
          "geo": {
            "lat": "-43.9509",
            "lng": "-34.4618"
          }
        },
        "phone": "010-692-6593 x09125",
        "website": "anastasia.net",
        "company": {
          "name": "Deckow-Crist",
          "catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency",
          "bs": "synergize scalable supply-chains"
        }
      }

    ]
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map((value: string) => this._filter(value))
    )
  }

  myControl = new FormControl()

  // filteredOptions: Observable<string[]> | undefined
  onSubmit(){
    this.isSubmitted = true;
    this.customerName= "customername:"+this.checkforcustomer;
    console.log('cutomer name provided',this.customerName)
    this.service.fetchCustomerdetails(this.customerName).subscribe((res) => 
    {
      this.customerResponse=res[0]
      console.log('Customer Details here',this.customerResponse)
    })
  }

  displayFn(subject:any) {
    console.log('subject',subject)
    return subject ? subject.name : undefined
  }

  private _filter(value: string): string[] {
    console.log('ss',value)
    const filterValue = value.toString().toLowerCase()
    return this.options.filter((option: { name: { toString: () => string; }; 
  }) =>
      option.name.toString().toLowerCase().includes(filterValue)
    )
  }

  onChange(deviceValue:any) {
    this.checkforcustomer=deviceValue;
    console.log('customerName',this.checkforcustomer)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `filterOptions` is `Observable<string[]>` but not `Observable<any[]>`. Hence you cannot access `name` from a `string`.

```js
filteredOptions: Observable<string[]> | undefined
```

---

### Solution

1. Change `filterOptions` to `Observable<any[]>` type.

```js
filteredOptions: Observable<any[]> | undefined;
```

2. Change `_filter` function with `any[]` return type.

```js
private _filter(value: string): any[] {
  ...
}
```

[Sample Solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-f24ruj?file=src/app/customer/customer.component.ts)